# How to load test web application developed on asp.net mvc3?

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, profiling, load-testing

I want to load test the web application that we're working on? Can you name some automated load testing tool for a website developed on asp.net mvc3? I would like to develop it for concurrent 100 users, 200 users and so on. We want to test it with many users and test the load that creates on the application and server.

BTW, we're also running profiler at the same time to find the application bottlenecks so that we can find code that is slow that we can improve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of different options; they vary in all kinds of exciting ways.

I use the open source [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for this kind of testing - it's not hugely user friendly, but is very powerful once you get used to it, and the lack of licensing restrictions means you can use it in all sorts of configurations.

Some of our projects have glued JMeter into the continuous integration cycle, running performance tests on nightly builds. Some projects need to scale to huge numbers of users, and we use JMeter in the cloud (there are some service providers who can do this too).

it works nicely with Asp.Net MVC apps.

Comment: Hadn't seen httperf before - but it seems to be aimed at testing implementations of the HTTP protocol, rather than websites. It doesn't seem straightforward to test user journeys - "go to home page, click login, provide user credentials, view account history". You probably need that feature to test your web application...

Comment: We have tested is using Wcat 6.3. Here is the link http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1466

Comment: JMeter is great! Tutorial aimed at MVC: http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/06/load-testing-aspnet-mvc-part-2-jmeter.html

Answer (score 0):

We are currently load testing our MVC application and the external company uses a product called LoadRunner.

However, depending on how intricate your testing is you could use the `WebClient` class as a base to run your own volume tests.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use WebClient to run volume tests?

Comment: You simulate the calls you would make from the browser.  You can use Fiddler to see what the traffic is and subclass WebClient to add cookie support (SO has answers for that also).

Comment: I'm totally clue less what do you mean, can you please explain or provide me the links.. that will be wonderful to start with it.

Comment: Lets' say you have a login form.  You can `POST` the values to your MVC action using the WebClient's `UploadValues` method where you will be validated and your session created.  All other `GET` calls can be made with the `DownloadString` method to call the various urls and you can parse the resulting string for certain values.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

Web Performance [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/load-tester.html) works very well with .NET apps. We test a lot of them (disclaimer: I work for Web Performance and am closely involved with the product).

Answer (score 0):

We have integrated with Fiddler load testing tool called [StresStimulus](http://www.toolsjournal.com/testing-articles/item/438-stresstimulus-a-hot-favorite-among-web-testers)